# Finding a straight in a cribbage

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## Background

For those of you not familiar with Cribbage, it uses a standard 52 card deck with aces being always low.  A player's hand consists of 4 cards, and there is 1 turn card that all players can use to help score their hand.

So for a little practice problem for myself, I wrote a we bit of VBA and had all ~12.9 million possible scoring combination printed in an excel sheet.  I assigned each card an integer 1 to 52 and set it up so that each suit is a sequential block of 13 cards.  1-13 = Clubs, 14-26 = Diamonds, 27-39 = Hearts, and 40-52 = Spades.  I dealt each card into its own separate cell in adjacent columns.  Ie `B1:E1` is the hand and `F1` is the turn.  The hand (B1:E1) is also organised in the lowest card ID number (not card value) is on the left and the highest is on the right.

Then I started tinkering with how to score any given hand using excel formulas.  So far I have been able to check for a 4 and 5 card flush (flush=all cards same suit), Pairs (which includes three and four of a kind), 15 combinations (2,3,4 and 5 cards).  What I have outstanding are checking for straights and 1 point for the knob (Jack in hand matches suit of turn).  Checking the later should be easy enough.

A straight in Cribbage is the largest sequence/series of cards.  You cannot go around the clock, (ie 3,2,1,13,12 or 3,2,A,K,Q).  You cannot count the two 4 card straights of a 5 card straight as only the largest is counted.  However you can count double straight such as 2,2,3,4,5 or 2,3,4,4,5.  Each card in a straight counts as 1 point.

## Problem

I am not sure how to identify a four card straight when there is a double/pair of one of the cards.  ei. 2,3,4,5,16 or 2,3,4,5,15 or 2,3,4,5,18. (Face value: 2,3,3,4,5 or 2,2,3,4,5 or 2,3,4,5,5)

## What have I tried so far

I was able to figure out the 5 card straight easy enough using:  MOD to convert the cards to face value and strip the suit, AGGREGATE to sort the cards, then checking if each card was the appropriate difference from the first card.  The formula is a bit unwieldy but works:

```
=AND(
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),2)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=1,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),3)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=2,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),4)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=3,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),5)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=4
)*5
```

So then I started on the 4 card sequence. I am able to get it to work as long as it not a double straight.

```
=OR(AND(AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),2)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=1,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),3)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=2,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),4)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=3,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),5)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)<>4),
AND(AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),2)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-1,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),3)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-2,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),4)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-3,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),5)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)<>-4))
*4
```

Or to break it out into its separate checks.

```
=AND(
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),2)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=1,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),3)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=2,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),4)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=3,
AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),5)-AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)<>4
)*4

AND(
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),2)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-1,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),3)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-2,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),4)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)=-3,
AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),5)-AGGREGATE(14,6,MOD(B1:F1,13),1)<>-4
)*4
```

## Question

How to find a four card straight with a double/pair using excel formulas preferably in a single cell eventually.  I do not mind multiple cells for building and understanding the formula.

Is there a better way to identify a straight using excel formulas?

I am hoping to build on the concept for 4 card straight, when figured out, to look after 3 card straights.

## Sample Data

```
| B | C | D | E | F  |
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 14 |   <= 5 card straight
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 16 |   <= 2 X 4 card straight
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 15 |   <= 2 X 4 card straight
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 18 |   <= 2 X 4 card straight
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 20| 5  |   <= 1 X 4 card straight
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 8 | 10 |   <= Not a straight
```

## Excel Version

I am running excel 2013

Comment: isn't 19 a 6 of diamonds, making the last a 5 card straight?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, I thought I had started that example with the ace.  I will change the 6 of diamonds to the 7

Comment: Here's a related question that I answered a few weeks ago - it certainly passed some time during lockdown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705426/classifying-flops-by-the-number-of-possible-straights-using-spreadsheet/61719116#61719116

Comment: @TomSharpe Did a quick glace at that question and appears very similar in nature.  I am going to need to read through it again and give it some time to digest.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @TomSharpe It seems both your solution and Scott's rely on SEQUENCE.  I tried that command in excel 2013 and it does not appear to be there.  I liked the sliding window concept.  Will see what I can finagle with that concept.  Right now I am trying to think of a way to eliminate and count duplicates within the straight potentially then multiply by the number of duplicates.  Though I don't think I can do that without permanent helper columns/tables

Comment: Glad it was potentially helpful. I haven't got Sequence in my version of Excel either, but you should be able to achieve the same effect (albeit more long-windedly)  by a row() and indirect or index combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use SUMPRODUCT with AGGREGATE:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{1,2,3,4})-AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{2,3,4,5})=1))=4,"5 card straight",
 IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{1,2,3,4})-AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{2,3,4,5})=1))=3,AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,1)-AGGREGATE(15,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,1)=3),"2 X 4 card straight",
IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{1,2,3,4})-AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{2,3,4,5})=1))=3,OR(AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,2)-AGGREGATE(15,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,1)=3,AGGREGATE(14,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,1)-AGGREGATE(15,7,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,2)=3)),"1 X 4 card straight","Not a Straight")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing 2 things.  1)  MOD(B1-1)+1 to get the card face value. 2) {1,2,3,4} as a manual array to get it to loop through things!  I am currently reading the 4 card straight section to figure out what I was missing.

Comment: I was going to ask why sumproduct instead of sum when I suddenly realized this is not a CSE formula to begin with!  I wish I could give more than a +1