# Counting Pairs in Cribbage Hand

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## Background

This is a followup question to my previous [finding a straight in a cribbage hand question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880243/finding-a-straight-in-a-cribbage)

## Objective

Count the number of pairs, then score 2 points for each pair.

## What I have Tried

I currently have two different working methods for counting pairs.  I was trying to find something potentially better and trying to work with manual arrays (hope that is the right term)  ie. {2,3,4}

Working formulas are:

```
=(SUM(--(AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,1)=AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{2,3,4,5})))
+SUM(--(AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,2)=AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{3,4,5})))
+SUM(--(AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,3)=AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{4,5})))
+(AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,4)=AGGREGATE(15,6,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,5)))*2
```

and

```
=((MOD(B1-1,13)+1=MOD(C1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(B1-1,13)+1=MOD(D1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(B1-1,13)+1=MOD(E1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(B1-1,13)+1=MOD(F1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(C1-1,13)+1=MOD(D1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(C1-1,13)+1=MOD(E1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(C1-1,13)+1=MOD(F1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(D1-1,13)+1=MOD(E1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(D1-1,13)+1=MOD(F1-1,13)+1)
+(MOD(E1-1,13)+1=MOD(F1-1,13)+1))*2
```

I liked the ability to use {2,3,4,5} to help build all the possible combinations.  However AGGREGATE is performing a sort step that I do not actually need.  I was trying to tinker with INDEX to bypass the sort step and I thought it was one of those functions that performs array operations without being an array like AGGREGATE or SUMPRODUCT.  However I could not seem to get it to work.  This is what I was trying:

```
=SUM(--((MOD(INDEX(B1:F1,1)-1,13)+1)=(MOD(INDEX(B1:F1,{2,3,4,5})-1,13)+1)))
=SUM(--((MOD(INDEX(B1:F1,1,1)-1,13)+1)=(MOD(INDEX(B1:F1,1,{2,3,4,5})-1,13)+1)))
```

Note this is just a proof of concept for checking the first card against the rest of the hand and the turn card.  I did not see a point of building out the rest of the formula if I could not get the first part to work.  I tried it as both a 1D and 2D reference in case it made a difference...it did not!  I also tried it with SUMPRODUCT instead of just SUM and I also tried CSE entry.

## Question

Is my thought on using INDEX wrong?  Is there a better way with formulas to check for all the potential pairings?

## Sample Data

```
|  B |  C |  D |  E |  F |   POINTS
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 | 14 | 27 | 40 |  2 |  <= 12 (4 of a kind, 6 pairs)
|  1 |  2 | 27 | 28 | 14 |  <= 8  (1 triple and 1 double aka full house in poker, 4 pairs)
|  1 | 14 | 27 | 28 | 52 |  <= 6  (1 triple, 3 pairs)
|  1 |  2 | 27 | 28 | 52 |  <= 4  (2 pairs)
|  1 |  2 | 14 | 51 | 52 |  <= 2  (1 pair)
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 | 52 |  <= 0  (no pair)
```

## Excel Version

Excel 2013

Comment: I meant to mention I was tinkering with the {2,3} based on ScottCraner's answer to the previous question.Trying to build on what I am learning and reinforcing new method for me.

Comment: This one is more difficult as it requires the formula to loop twice, and formulas do not like doing that, but let me think.

Comment: Yeah I thought I had all the scoring licked yesterday.  Turned out I missed a big error in scoring 15s so tweaked that one a bit, then I started refining most scoring methods.  I find it really quite interesting the number of different approaches one can take.  Unfortunately I do not always see the benefit or one method over another.

Comment: I do not play cribbage but does the first also not have two triples?

Comment: @Scott, Technically yes, but a triplet is actually 3 unique pairs.  In Crib the score for 4 of a kind, is the same as counting up the unique pairs that can be formed. Same goes for triples/3 of a kind. 1H-1S, 1H-1D, 1S-1D  would be the three unique pairs you could form if you had 1H, 1S, 1D, in your hand/turn.  You would score two points for each pair, so a triple is worth 6.

Comment: Cool question but confusing me to bits. No cribbage experience here. I started fooling around with `FILTERXML` but realized I don't understand the scoring =). I bet Scott will figure it out (no pressure hehe)

Comment: I guess what I am saying is you can either Identify 4 of a kind and award 12 point, Identify 3 of a kind and award 6 points, ID a full house for 8, etc...instead of counting pairs.  You wind up with the same score either way.

Comment: It is probably a piece of cake to loop through the combinations with VBA, but I find using formulas far more educational and interesting.

Comment: @JvdV  Scoring is interesting and pretty basic.  you have 5 categories to score in:4 or 5 
 card Flush (all same suit) 1 point for each card.  3 to 5 card Straight (only longest counts but you can have double straights) 1 point per card, Pairs 2 points per card, 15s, each unique way to sum to 15 counts as 2 points (face cards worth 10).

Comment: Currently i am at the point that we would need to use helper columns as using COUNTIFS will be required with Offset, but i am still playing.

Comment: @JvdV oh and Aces are always 1 and for straight you cant wrap around the clock 3-2-A-K-Q.  Only A-2-3-4-5.  And the one point I forgot to mention is if you have a Jack of the same suit as the turn card, you get 1 point.

Comment: I can do it with TEXTJOIN or helper columns.  But not with formula that work in 2010.

Comment: @ScottCraner I actually put TEXTJOIN VBA script that you wrote into a common library for my work laptop in case I ever needed it for one of you amazing (some might use confounding) TEXTJOINT solutions.

Comment: At this point I cannot come up with a more succinct formula than below, so I will not even embarrass myself with the monstrosity I came up with.  I tend to get anchored at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought of this which seemed a good idea last thing at night. Will have to see if it's still any good in the morning:

```
SUM(--(A1:E1=TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)))-5
```

entered as an array formula. This deliberately counts each pair twice, to get two points for each pair, but then you also get five because there is always a match on the diagonal of the resulting matrix so that needs to be subtracted.

[image]

**EDIT**

Here you go

```
=SUM(--(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)=MOD(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)-1,13)))-5
```

[image]

Comment: here is a version with MOD and SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)=TRANSPOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13))))-5`  And man am I upset with myself.  I actually tried something similar but was too anchored on my initial thought to see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Ah, thanks - for some reason sumproduct wouldn't seem to work for me last night.

Comment: So I was trying to wrap my head around this.  I initially thought when you ran an array formula, take this answer for example, that all the A1s got evaluated, then the B1s then the C1s in sequence. So even with the transpose you would wind up with a 1D array/matrix.  However when I read the description and evaluate the formula, it appears like it evaluates A1 to E1 for the range reference and only A1 in the transpose.  Then it re-evaluates A1 to E1 for the B1 in the transpose and so on.  As a result you wind up with a 2D square array/matrix?

Comment: @ScottCraner SUMPRODUCT does not work for me either unless its is entered as a CSE formula. However if you enter as a CSE formula, you do not need SUMPRODUCT and it will work fine with just SUM. I am guessing it has something to do with TRANSPOSE similar to IF statements need CSE entry and do not always work with SUMPRODUCT/AGGREGATE

Comment: @ForwardEd that may be, my version does not require CSE.  Older version may.

Comment: @ScottCraner does the newer version of SUMPRODUCT now work with IFs or does it still require CSE?

Comment: With the dynamic array formulas CSE is not needed.