# Counting 15's in Cribbage Hand

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## Background

This is a followup question to my previous [finding a straight in a cribbage hand question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880243/finding-a-straight-in-a-cribbage) and [Counting Pairs in Cribbage Hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903517/counting-pairs-in-cribbage-hand)

## Objective

Count the number of ways cards can be combined to a total of 15, then score 2 points for each pair. Ace worth 1, and J,Q,K are worth 10.

## What I have Tried

So my first poke at a solution required 26 different formulas.  Basically I checked each possible way to combine cards to see if the total was 15.  1 way to add 5 cards, 5 ways to add 4 cards, 10 ways to add 3 cards, and 10 ways to add 2 cards.  I thought I had this licked until I realized I was only looking at combinations, I had not considered the fact that I had to cap the value of cards 11, 12, and 13 to 10.  I initially tried an array formula something along the lines of:

```
MIN(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,10)
```

But the problem with this is that MIN takes the minimum value of all results not the individual results compared to 10.

I then tried it with an IF function, which worked, but involved the use of CSE formula even wehen being used with SUMPRODUCT which is something I try to avoid when I can

```
IF(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1<11,MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,10)
```

Then I stumble on [an answer to a question in code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158123) which I modified to lead me to this formula, which I kind of like for some strange reason, but its a bit long in repetitive use:

```
--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2)
```

My current working formulas are:

```
5 card check
=(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2))=15)*2

4 card checks
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2),{1,2,3,4}))=15)*2
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2),{1,2,3,5}))=15)*2
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2),{1,2,4,5}))=15)*2
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2),{1,3,4,5}))=15)*2
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(15,6,--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2),{2,3,4,5}))=15)*2

3 card checks 
same as 4 card checks using all combinations for 3 cards in the {1,2,3}.
There are 10 different combinations, so 10 different formulas.
```

The 2 card check was based on [the solution by Tom in Counting Pairs in Cribbage Hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62904664/5336948) and all two cards are checked with a single formula. (yes it is CSE)

```
2 card check
{=SUM(--(--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2)+TRANSPOSE(--MID("01020304050607080910101010",1+(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)*2),2))=15))}
```

## Question

Can the 3 and 4  card combination sum check be brought into a single formula similar to the 2 card check?
Is there a better way to convert cards 11,12,13 to a value of 10?

## Sample Data

```
|  B |  C |  D |  E |  F |   POINTS
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 | 17 | 31 |  <= 2  (all 5 add to 15)
|  1 |  2 |  3 | 17 | 32 |  <= 2  (Last 4 add to 15)
| 11 | 18 | 31 | 44 |  5 |  <= 16 ( 4x(J+5), 4X(5+5+5) )
|  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 52 |  <= 4  (6+9, 7+8)
|  1 |  3 |  7 |  8 | 52 |  <= 2  (7+8)
|  2 |  3 |  7 |  9 | 52 |  <= 2  (2+3+K)
|  2 |  4 |  6 | 23 | 52 |  <= 0  (nothing add to 15)
```

## Excel Version

Excel 2013

Comment: one that is slightly shorter: `CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)`

Comment: @ScottCraner  I think I tried `--SUBSTITUE(MOD(B1:F1-1,13)+1,{11,12,13},10)` but it did not work for me at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `5`:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))=15)*2
```

For `4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,ROW($1:$5),{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,5;1,2,4,5;1,3,4,5;2,3,4,5}),ROW($1:$4)^0)=15))*2
```

For `3`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,ROW($1:$10),{1,2,3;1,2,4;1,2,5;1,3,4;1,3,5;1,4,5;2,3,4;2,3,5;2,4,5;3,4,5}),ROW($1:$3)^0)=15))*2
```

For 2:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--((CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))+(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)))=15))
```

All together:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))=15)*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,ROW($1:$5),{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,5;1,2,4,5;1,3,4,5;2,3,4,5}),ROW($1:$4)^0)=15))*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,ROW($1:$10),{1,2,3;1,2,4;1,2,5;1,3,4;1,3,5;1,4,5;2,3,4;2,3,5;2,4,5;3,4,5}),ROW($1:$3)^0)=15))*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--((CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))+(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)))=15))
```

[image]

For older versions we need to "trick" INDEX into accepting the arrays as Row and Column References:

We do that by using `N(IF({1},[thearray]))`

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))=15)*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,N(IF({1},ROW($1:$5))),N(IF({1},{1,2,3,4;1,2,3,5;1,2,4,5;1,3,4,5;2,3,4,5}))),ROW($1:$4)^0)=15))*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(INDEX(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)*ROW($1:$10)^0,N(IF({1},ROW($1:$10))),N(IF({1},{1,2,3;1,2,4;1,2,5;1,3,4;1,3,5;1,4,5;2,3,4;2,3,5;2,4,5;3,4,5}))),ROW($1:$3)^0)=15))*2+
SUMPRODUCT(--((CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10))+(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)))=15))
```

This is a CSE That must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: edit]

Comment: You will need to let me know if it requires CSE, but I believe it will, but I could not come up with any way that did not use MMULT, outside of the method you already have.

Comment: Also another formula that returns an array of the values `MATCH(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})` can replace all the `CHOOSE(MOD(A1:E1-1,13)+1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10)` and is a little shorter.

Comment: Love seeing these alternate approaches.  Very educational for me and very much appreciated.  I had not even considered looking at matrix multiplication.  I have not had a chance to incorporate/test this out yet,but will let you know about the CSE.

Comment: @ForwardEd I still needed to put in all the patterns, but as a 2 dimensional array so it is one formula over many.

Comment: As a complete aside, the third test case is known as the perfect hand. It scores a total of 29.  16 for 15s, 12 for pairs, and 1 for jack suit in hand matching the turn card suit.  And on that note, it is impossible to score a hand worth 19 points.

Comment: Was this part `ROW($1:$4)^0` just to get an array of 1's?

Comment: Yes, theoretically it could be replaced with `{1;1;1;1}`

Comment: I think i have run out of Cribbage scoring questions, so I won't be able to keep you entertained for the rest of the week.  Again thank for the insight on different approaches.

Comment: I was just about to ask you to stop, I can't concentrate on my work till I have worked it out. :)

Comment: Hrmmm wondering if I should wait until friday to comment.  So I copied the 4 card formula and pasted into Excel and hit enter.  It displayed #VALUE.  So I hit F2 and did CSE to make it an array formula and it displayed #VALUE.  Interesting that as a regular formula, it blows up at the first evaluation of the range used in MOD (yes I adjusted that to suit my range B1:F1). However when I evaluate the formula as a CSE I can step through most of it without error.  Its basically blowing up at the MMULT step.

Comment: I used the 3 test row data when evaluating the formula.  I can see the 10,5,5,5,5 repeated 10 times to create the matrix for the first part of index.  Row$1:$5 evaluates to 1.  Not sure if that is because evaluate has a limit on the depth of iteration it displays.  The manual combinations { } also evaluates to 1.  So INDEX evaluates to 10.  Row($1:$4)^0 evaluates to 1;1;1;1.  That leaves the formula sitting at `SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(--10,{1;1;1;1}))*2` .  The next evaluation displays the #VALUE error `SUMPRODUCT(--(#VALUE!=15))*2.

Comment: Another oddity.  On the first evaluation of the choose function, nothing seems to happen.I wait a bit in case I am doing it to fast and hit it a second time. And then it evaluate choose.

Comment: I can understand ROW($1:$10)^1 for 3 and 2 card combinations as there are 10 combination for each.  Is this what is supposed to be represented by this, a row for each combination?  which in this case would be 5 for the 4 card combination?

Comment: There may be something different in versions. Let me play tomorrow with a different version.

Comment: I am having the opposite problem of you Scott!  Work keeps getting in the way and I cannot concentrate on the Cribbage fun stuff!

Comment: @ScottCranner Just tested it out and it seems to be working.   Going to step through it a couple of times to figure out how the whole thing is working.  I did some manual matrix operations to see some of the stuff you were doing earlier.